# 0 DF in regression in SAS enterprise guide

Tags: sas, regression

I created dummies in SAS (part of the codes below) and run regression (threw away M23). It was working fine. But then I tried to group them by age since we don't have enough members. I ran it the same way and threw away one age group (M20to24 since this group has the highest membership). Now some of my variables have 0 DF. Does anyone know what went wrong? 
I got the message - Note: Model is not full rank. Least-squares solutions for the parameters are not unique. Some statistics will be misleading. A reported DF of 0 or B means that the estimate is biased. The following parameters have been set to 0, since the variables are a linear combination of other variables as shown.

```
  data  Table;
set Table;
M0=(AgeGender = '0M');
M1=(AgeGender = '1M');
M2=(AgeGender = '2M');
M3=(AgeGender = '3M');
M4=(AgeGender = '4M');
M5to9=(AgeGender = ' 5to9M');
M10to14=(AgeGender = '10to14M');
M15to19=(AgeGender = '15to19M');
M20to24=(AgeGender = '20to24M');
M25to29=(AgeGender = '25to29M');
M30to34=(AgeGender = '30to34M');
M35to39=(AgeGender = '35to39M');
M40to44=(AgeGender = '40to44M');
M45to49=(AgeGender = '45to49M');
M50to54=(AgeGender = '50to54M');
M55to59=(AgeGender = '55to59M');
M60to64=(AgeGender = '60to64M');
M65Plus=(AgeGender = '65+M');
F0=(AgeGender = '0F');
F1=(AgeGender = '1F');
F2=(AgeGender = '2F');
F3=(AgeGender = '3F');
F4=(AgeGender = '4F');
F5to9=(AgeGender = ' 5to9F');
F10to14=(AgeGender = '10to14F');
F15to19=(AgeGender = '15to19F');
F20to24=(AgeGender = '20to24F');
F25to29=(AgeGender = '25to29F');
F30to34=(AgeGender = '30to34F');
F35to39=(AgeGender = '35to39F');
F40to44=(AgeGender = '40to44F');
F45to49=(AgeGender = '45to49F');
F50to54=(AgeGender = '50to54F');
F55to59=(AgeGender = '55to59F');
F60to64=(AgeGender = '60to64F');
F65Plus=(AgeGender = '65+F');
Dep = (Relationship = 'Dep');
Mandatory = (Mand_Vo = 'Mandatory');
run;

ods output ParameterEstimates=Parameter_Estimates; 
proc reg data= Table;
model logPMPM = 
M0
M1
M2
M3
M4
M5to9
M10to14
M15to19

M25to29
M30to34
M35to39
M40to44
M45to49
M50to54
M55to59
M60to64
M65Plus
F0
F1
F2
F3
F4
F5to9
F10to14
F15to19
F20to24
F25to29
F30to34
F35to39
F40to44
F45to49
F50to54
F55to59
F60to64
F65Plus;
weight Membership;
run; 
ods output close;
```

Comment: Some of your dummy variables are coded exactly the same. Nothing you've shown would allow us to tell you what.

Comment: ok I have pasted all the codes

Comment: Which ones have the 0?

Comment: M5to9 has DF = 0

Comment: So I have tried it multiple ways to see what could fix with the degree of freedom problem. I thought maybe because my data is too summarized and not enough variables. So I use another dataset that's less summarized, so it has more lines . But still having the same DF issue.

Comment: So I don't have this problem when I tried to run individual age. I only got this problem when I group the age together.

Comment: and now I have 400k observations, so that shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you have overlaps or identical complimentary data variables but that's by definition. Your data is likely having that occur by chance, which is harder to find. You can likely find this by crossing variables that you suspect may be related or doing a pair wise scatter plot (PROC SGSCATTER) and seeing which two overlap almost identically.

You're correct, you wouldn't get this behaviour with continuous values because they're continuous and less likely to overlap exactly. In general, it's considered best practice to NOT categorize/bin variables when you can keep them continuous. The boundaries are artificial, does a 34 year old really differ from that 36 year old? What if all the people in that age group are 34 compared to the 36 in the 35 to 39 age group? You may not find a difference, but if your distribution was everyone at 39 vs everyone at 31 you may find more of a difference. Keeping the data continuous avoids these manufactured issues.

Comment: Thank you. So I was grouping them because of low membership for some age. Do you mean bucketing them differerently would help?

Comment: Yes, try using bigger groups for your age.

Comment: ok. So I tried to run it without the grouping, and it worked fine. But I added other variables to the regression (hoping to get rid of the noise), and now the DF is 0 for many of the age and gender groups. The new variables somewhat depend on each others. I think that's the problem (?) How would you avoid that?

Comment: When you treat a variable as continuous you remove it from CLASS statement so you should have a single estimate for class and gender, not multiple estimates.

Comment: so I tried different groupings, and I think it makes most sense to not group them. But my curve is not very smooth now. e.g. 34 is more expensive than 35, and 35 is cheaper than 36. But ideally the cost would slowly goes up by age. Is there a way to maybe smooth it in sas?

Comment: It would be very weird to have that happen with age, you must have an interaction somehow? Otherwise I would expect your model to look something like: `model logPMPM = sex age sex*age; weight membership;`  where age is continuous and sex is a 0/1 variable. And if you have weights you may want to be using PROC SURVEYREG if you have survey data or need to look at the variance at all.